# Css file not loaded on first time, but available in browser when i manually open the css url

Tags: gulp, less

I am using gulp task in my project, and when i open the project in browser, sometimes it says app.css is not available, but when i enter the same css url to another tab it opens correctly. cant understand is it a gulp problem or some other.

Comment: Have you got the exact error message? What exactly says "app.css is not available"? Is your browser returning a 404 or is something else giving you an error?

Comment: In network tab, it says status 502

Comment: any suggestions for the issue??